# Hidden elements still taking up space on dropdown navigation

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble with a navigation menu I am creating. I am using a combination of `scaleY` and `transition` to have the dropdown smoothly open when it's hovered over. However, currently the dropdown links are currently still taking up space on the screen (see snippet) instead of only doing so when the parent link is hovered.

I have tried adding `display:none` and `display:block;` to the relevant elements; which works, but it removes the smooth transition effect that the `transform` creates.

```css
.site-navigation {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.menu li {
  display:block;
}

.menu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  visibility:visible;
  transform:scaleY(1);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: visibility 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav class="site-navigation">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Dropdown Link</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mok21ega/)

Comment: hidden vs display
maybe animate height will help

Comment: instead of `visibility:hidden` just use `display: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use max-height or height and give transition to that too like

```
.dropdown-menu {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  max-height : 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
.menu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
 visibility:visible;
 transform:scaleY(1);
 max-height : 80px;
}
```

for smooth transition you need to set static or dynamically max-height value not auto
if you want to use only css you have to give a static max-height to your element when it will show but if you want to get element's height dynamically you can use javascript

```css
.site-navigation {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.menu li {
  display:block;
}

.menu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  visibility:visible;
  transform:scaleY(1);
    max-height : 80px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  max-height : 0;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="site-navigation">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Dropdown Link</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Normal Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution:

```
.site-navigation {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.menu li {
  display:block;
}

.menu .dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  visibility:visible;
  transform:scaleY(1);
  height: auto;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  height: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
  transition: visibility 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pgurav/zjov0nb1/2/

Comment: This is basically what I'm looking for, hadn't thought of adjusting the height values. Cheers